# Create a game loop in Java for a 2D space shooter game

Tags: java, multithreading, 2d

I'm having some trouble figuring out the best way to implement a game loop in my game. I'm trying to a make a gradius clone and I've run into some performance issues using swing. I'm thinking about using threads but I have not used them before.

The particular problem I am running into is how to get a delta time passed into my enemy sub class' update method. I need that delta time so that I can get my enemies moving on sine waves. Anyone know the best way to get a dt from a thread and using it to make my enemies move on sin/cos waves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a good 2d game engine.

Check [this very useful SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/293079/java-2d-game-frameworks) thread for recommendations.

Comment: I don't want to have to use a 2D game engine. This is really just an exercise in what I've learned in Java so far. I want to be able to do this using swing and graphics/graphics2D. I appreciate your suggestion though, I'll keep this in mind for a future larger project.

Comment: Fair enough. Maybe have a look at how some of the open source engines do it, for inspiration..